# redux action creator -> dispatch doesn't fire from thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Subject line summarizes this issue pretty clearly.

Attempting to post an item to DB and then retrieve a fresh collection from the POST request.

```
export function addEntry(props, id, func) {    
    console.log("Add fn fired")    
    return dispatch => {
      console.log('Dispatch fired')
      return makeStaffEntry('post', id, props)
              .then(response => {            
                console.log(response, "RESPONSE")
                func()
                dispatch(receiveEntry(response.data))        
      })
    }
}
```

The first console log fires, but the rest do not. I cannot test makeStaffEntry because I cannot get the "dispatch fired" log.

store config

```
export default function configureStore(initialState, history) {
  const middleware = [thunk, promiseMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)];
  if (__DEVCLIENT__) {
    middleware.push(createLogger());
  }

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.devToolsExtension !== 'undefined' ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  ));

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('reducers', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('reducers');
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
```

Comment: How are you using `addEntry()`?  Are you passing the returned thunk to `dispatch()`, either manually or by using a pre-bound version of `addEntry`?  If so, do you have the thunk middleware configured for your store?

Comment: it's a callback to handleSubmit for redux form. I'm confused by the second question: are you asking if I dispatch(addEntry)? If so, I do not.

Comment: Can you post the related code where you invoke addEntry? Since it is in the form of an async action creator, you probably have to dispatch it like markerikson suggested.

Comment: Yeah, that's your problem.  The whole point of Redux is that to make _anything_ useful happen, you call `store.dispatch()` and pass something in.  Normally what you pass in is an action object, but in this case, we're going to pass in a function and let the thunk middleware intercept it.  And, in fact, what you need to do is: `dispatch(addEntry())`.  Note that the inner returned function is what gets passed in.

Comment: I don't understand, where should dispatch(addEntry) be called if it's the primary action creator? can  you give an example of what you mean?